# How does default prioritization work?

Tags: rimworld

In RimWorld you can toggle between custom prioritization and default prioritization.

**How does the game determine the defaults?**

**What are the defaults?**

**Do they ever change or shift?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It actually tells you on the work tab.

[image]

On default prioritization (and for custom prioritization when priority levels are the same), jobs on the left are at a higher priority than jobs on the right.